# Definition of infinite limit

Tags: real-analysis

Following is an exercise I solved, it is not homework so I don't know how to check my solution. Can you please check the solution for me? The exercise is this:

Modify the definition of convergent sequence to obtain a definition of convergence to $\infty$ and then use your definition to show that $x_n = \sqrt{n}$ converges to $\infty$. What does your definition say about the sequence $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,...$

My solution:  The new definition is: For every $\varepsilon$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $x_n > \varepsilon$. Then: Let $\varepsilon > 0$. Let $N$ be such that $N > \varepsilon^2$. Then $n>N$ implies $\sqrt{n} > \sqrt{N} > \varepsilon$. The sequence $1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,...$ does not converge to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have written down so far is correct. Can you also give a full proof that $1,0,2,0,3,0,\ldots$ does not converge to $\infty$?

Comment: I did it also: for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is $n$ with $x_n=0<\varepsilon$.